# How to adjust date labels in ggplot? [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like this, with weeks ranging between 2018-03-25 to 2018-12-23:

```
   week       child     n  freq
 1 2018-03-25 FALSE   758 0.812
 2 2018-03-25 TRUE    176 0.188
 3 2018-04-01 FALSE   534 0.845
 4 2018-04-01 TRUE     98 0.155
 5 2018-04-08 FALSE   336 0.808
 6 2018-04-08 TRUE     80 0.192
 7 2018-04-15 FALSE   279 0.793
 8 2018-04-15 TRUE     73 0.207
 9 2018-04-22 FALSE   299 0.819
10 2018-04-22 TRUE     66 0.181
```

When I use ggplot to create a time-series, the date labels on the x-axis always show January, even though I have no data in January. How do I remove this or adjust the date labels to properly display the ending month?

Code to generate the plot:

```
library(ggplot)
library(hrbrthemes)

ggplot(data, aes(week, freq, fill = child)) +
  geom_area(position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#006FB7", "#F18E00"),
                    labels = c("Adults", "Children")) +
  scale_y_percent() +
  theme_ipsum_rc(base_family = "Times New Roman", base_size = 10, grid = "none")
```

dput of data:

```
structure(list(week = structure(c(17706, 17678, 17699, 17671, 17804, 17664, 17790, 17734, 17685, 17622, 17650, 17657, 17797, 
                                  17839, 17832, 17720, 17881, 17643, 17748, 17811, 17727, 17615, 17713, 17818, 17629, 17769, 
                                  17636, 17846, 17762, 17825, 17741, 17755, 17853, 17776, 17783, 17867, 17888, 17874, 17860, 
                                  17692, 17692, 17860, 17874, 17888, 17867, 17783, 17776, 17853, 17755, 17741, 17825, 17762, 
                                  17846, 17636, 17769, 17629, 17818, 17713, 17615, 17727, 17811, 17748, 17643, 17881, 17720, 
                                  17832, 17839, 17797, 17657, 17650, 17622, 17685, 17734, 17790, 17664, 17804, 17671, 17699, 
                                  17678, 17706), class = "Date"), 
               child = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                         FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                         FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                         TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                         TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                         TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
               n = c(110L, 86L, 97L, 54L, 161L, 1408L, 206L, 131L, 205L, 534L, 241L, 300L, 179L, 110L, 74L, 108L, 84L, 299L, 
                     112L, 204L, 78L, 758L, 158L, 187L, 336L, 50L, 279L, 44L, 78L, 212L, 69L, 92L, 55L, 97L, 110L, 73L, 15L, 
                     101L, 59L, 1L, 1L, 32L, 42L, 6L, 25L, 37L, 32L, 18L, 27L, 20L, 61L, 22L, 12L, 73L, 12L, 80L, 44L, 37L, 
                     176L, 18L, 46L, 25L, 66L, 18L, 22L, 15L, 22L, 35L, 58L, 45L, 98L, 37L, 23L, 36L, 242L, 27L, 9L, 16L, 
                     12L, 14L), 
               freq = c(0.887, 0.878, 0.858, 0.857, 0.856, 0.853, 0.851, 0.851, 0.847, 0.845, 0.843, 0.838, 0.836, 0.833, 
                        0.831, 0.831, 0.824, 0.819, 0.818, 0.816, 0.812, 0.812, 0.81, 0.81, 0.808, 0.806, 0.793, 0.786, 
                        0.78, 0.777, 0.775, 0.773, 0.753, 0.752, 0.748, 0.745, 0.714, 0.706, 0.648, 0.5, 0.5, 0.352, 0.294, 
                        0.286, 0.255, 0.252, 0.248, 0.247, 0.227, 0.225, 0.223, 0.22, 0.214, 0.207, 0.194, 0.192, 0.19, 
                        0.19, 0.188, 0.188, 0.184, 0.182, 0.181, 0.176, 0.169, 0.169, 0.167, 0.164, 0.162, 0.157, 0.155, 
                        0.153, 0.149, 0.149, 0.147, 0.144, 0.143, 0.142, 0.122, 0.113)), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -80L))
```

Comment: I updated with the code used to generate the plot.

Comment: To make it reproducible, please use output of `dput(mydata)`.

Comment: Please review the code and make it fully reproducible by adding the packages you use. `injury_date` is not contained in the data you provide and please use `dput` to make it easier reproducible.
For me the plot starts with March and not with January, but I had to leave of the last to lines of code...

Comment: Right. It should start in March and end in December, but I have a date label that appears with Jan (instead of Dec) at the end of the area chart.

Comment: You can add `scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0))` to you ggplot-call to prevent the x-axis to expand beyond the data or you specify the limits you'd like to have (i.e. `scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2018-03-25", "2018-12-23")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kath mentioned above, you can use functionality of `scale_x_date()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(week, freq, fill = child)) +
  geom_area(position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#006FB7", "#F18E00"),
                    labels = c("Adults", "Children")) +
  scale_x_date(
    "Date",
    breaks = seq(min(dat$week), max(dat$week), by = "month"), 
    date_labels = "%b, %Y",
    ) +
  scale_y_continuous("Frquency", labels = scales::percent) +
  ggthemes::theme_tufte()
```

[image]